# Minmaxscaler inverse_transform doesn't work

Tags: python

my code is as followed:

## transform scale

```
X = dataset #(100, 18)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(X)
scaled_X = scaler.transform(X)
scaled_series = Series(scaled_X[:, 17])
print(scaled_series.head())
```

## invert transform

```
inverted_X = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_X)
inverted_series = Series(inverted_X[:, 17])
print(inverted_series.head())
```

the problem is that scaled_series and inverted_series are the same result, how should I correct the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the range of your dataset `X`. If we consider the formula for the MinMax scaler:

[image]

Should the range of `X` be [0,1], there will be no difference made as you will be subtracting 0 and dividing by 1. Thus, returning the same value.

Normalization is only viable for values which are not on the scale of 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is specific to your dataset. For instance, when I use an example dataset, the `scaled_series`and the `inverted_series` gave two different outputs:

```py
Scaled Series output:
0    0.729412
1    0.741176
2    0.741176
3    0.670588
4    0.870588
dtype: float32

Inverted Series output:
0    0.698347
1    0.706612
2    0.706612
3    0.657025
4    0.797521
dtype: float32
```

Both `scaled_series` and `inverted_series` gave different outputs but the values are close to each other. If you `scale` your data before using `MinMaxScalar`:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

X = scale(X)
```

Result:

```py
Scaled Series output:
0    0.729412
1    0.741176
2    0.741176
3    0.670588
4    0.870588
dtype: float32

Inverted Series output:
0   -0.188240
1   -0.123413
2   -0.123413
3   -0.512372
4    0.589678
dtype: float32
```

Now, the outputs are not close to each other, they are completely different.

Code:

---

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, scale
from pandas import Series

X, _ = fetch_olivetti_faces(return_X_y=True)
X = scale(X)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(X)
scaled_X = scaler.transform(X)
scaled_series = Series(scaled_X[:, 17])
print("\nScaled Series output:")
print(scaled_series.head())

inverted_X = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_X)
inverted_series = Series(inverted_X[:, 17])
print("\nInverted Series output:")
print(inverted_series.head())
```